# How does AWS postgres RDS read replication handle schema switching?

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds

I am wanting to know how an AWS postgres RDS does replication where I rename schemas to "swap" them within the read/write instance of the database.

Does it replicate this action to the read-replicas by sending on the "alter schema" rename commands I gave to my read/write instance?  Or after my renames, does it see wholly different sets of data in the schemas and do a whole new copy of each out to the read-replicas?

---

For example...

In my RDS instance I have a read/write instance of "my_mega_database" which I want to create read-replicas of for my applications to connect to.

Typically, in "my_mega_database" there are two schemas "my_data" and "my_data_old", whereby "my_data" contains data that was delivered last night, and "my_data_old" contains data from the previous night.  Each contains many tables and huge amounts of data.

If I were to do the following...

```
ALTER SCHEMA my_data_old RENAME TO my_data_tmp;
ALTER SCHEMA my_data RENAME TO my_data_old;
ALTER SCHEMA my_data_tmp RENAME TO my_data;
```

... I have affectively swapped these around.

My expectation is that these actions are replicated via the postgres WAL (ie: it sends the rename commands out to the replicas) and AWS RDS replication won't try and waste time copying huge amounts of data all over the place.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

(Speaking about PostgreSQL here, but RDS is probably similar.)

Renaming a schema (or any other object) is a small update in a catalog table, and no data are moved. Internally PostgreSQL uses only the numeric object ID, which stays the same.

You might wrap the three statements in a transaction to make the whole magic atomic.

The same is true on the standby, it is a trivial (meta)data modification.

The only thing that might be a problem are concurrent sessions holding locks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Laurenz.
Yep, didn't include above but yes, when we do such switching it is always in a single transaction.  And yep, understand the metadata nature of postgres.
Was primarily curious as to whether or not RDS replication would "replicate" that switch in the same fashion, and as importantly, in the order in which it appears in the transaction log.
For example, I would hate for a replica to be part way through replicating some inserts that it "saw" in the write instance, but then a "switch" (as above) occurs and the replica tries to do that while still copying rows :)

Comment: That cannot happen, at least in PostgreSQL. Data modifications are applied on the standby in the same order as on the primary. Otherwise recovery (which uses the same code) would not work reliably.